# Laravel relationship $this returns null when accessed with 'with' function

Tags: laravel, eloquent

While eager loading the relationship it return empty array as result but after getting the result relationship works fine..

Inside relation containing function $this has no attribute value while eager loading.

I have tried to eager load the relationship without eager loading and `$this` has all the attributes value.

- Controller

```
$temp = StipendCalcVols::with('stipendCalcTypes')->where('vol_id', 110)->first();
```

- Model

```
 public function stipendCalcTypes() {
        dd($this); // null attributes
        return $this->hasMany(StipendCalcTypes::class, 'table_id', 'vol_id')
            ->where('stipend_calc_id', $this->stipend_calc_id)->where('table_name', 'volunteers');
    }
```

`$this` should have attributes value.

Comment: What attribute values should `$this` have at this point in your opinion?

Comment: `$this->stipend_calc_id` or `$this->id` expecting model any attributes @Namoshek

Comment: Well, when the query builder eager loads the relationship, none of these attributes are set yet. This is also because you eager load for many models at the same time, not for each one individually.

Comment: Laravel doesn't support composite keys. Use this package: https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$temp = StipendCalcVols::where('vol_id', 110)->first();
$temp = $temp->load('stipendCalcTypes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Instead of:

```
$this->stipend_calc_id
```

Use this:

```
$this->attributes['stipend_calc_id']
```